# Heuristics for implementing good reading with columns

Tags: layout, desktop-application

Users read slower with wide columns, so having multiple columns makes sense for print, but it's [more complicated for desktop apps](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26360/do-columns-of-text-hurt-readability-on-websites). A desktop or laptop computer screen is too wide for fast reading, and multiple columns don't go well with vertical scrolling.

Which should we use, and why?

1. single column
2. multiple column

What are good heuristics for implementing it?

Comment: The concept of columns is best used for articles. Web apps generally don't have walls of text, it's more like a collection of objects grouped accordingly. The user will more likely be scanning, trying to find what they are looking for. Perhaps you should focus on making groups of objects clear and key identifiers easy to pick out when scanning. For example a title.

Answer (score 1):

The use of multiple columns for [text comes from newspaper layouts](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-reason-for-multi-column-layout-in-magazines-and-newspapers) and the time constraints involved in the days of physical type which was arranged by hand, where using multiple columns to a page allowed space to be changed easier should a new story break or an advert need to be placed/removed.

So it could be another hang up from an older medium that doesn't really need to be used in digital products, except for the fact we have become accustomed to this  layout of text in newspapers and magazines over the last 100 or so years.

Creating a fluid or responsive layout that allows the user to control the column width on their desktop/laptop computer might be the best approach, users of larger screens rarely have their [browser viewport maximised to fill the screen](http://beantin.se/computer-screens-browser-viewport-2012/). Similar to Wikipedia article pages.

**Edit:** When talking about columns I am only referring to the main body copy column, navigation or sidebar columns could be on the page too.

Comment: I don't think your Quora link supports characterizing multiple columns as a "hang up." I also don't think responsive design fully answers to issue of column number. On vertical mobile devices, one column makes sense, but it's more complicated for desktop or even landscape mobile ( [example](http://abramkj.com/2013/09/11/lsj-greek-english-lexicon-in-logos-for-ipad-reviewed-part-2/) ). One column doesn't fill 1024 pixels. What do you do with the rest?

Comment: You wouldn't want the column(s) of text to go to the very edge pixels of the screen anyway, you would have some sort of margin or max column width. The majority of users would expect a margin of some sort, from hundreds of years of printed products having margins.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work in print and it was generally known that the optimum line length was about 11 words - the reasoning is that, as you extend the length of the line, it becomes more difficult for the reader to return to the beginning of the next line - This naturally affects the speed that the reader can navigate they way through the text and affects comprehension where the text itself may make it difficult to spot skipped lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how people read when they are online. After many research, using heat maps, it has been found that people do not read but scan.

Research have shown that around 66 characters a line makes a faster and comfortable reading.

Today users have many choices, they are in hurry and they will switch immediately if they don't get what they are looking for. Under these circumstances, making them 2 columns scan can be costly for you.

My suggestion would be to keep the content:
1.

1. Well chunked (inverted pyramid way of writing)
2. Well supported with icons and photographs
3. Optimum line height and white space

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers of the question that you have linked, the answer actually is it depends. I have seen both the techniques use effectively.

**First example would be [Medium](https://medium.com/@southtopia/it-s-still-too-hard-to-get-your-first-bitcoin-bc78f4e69ab3).**

[image]

Here a single column works beautifully as the whitespace helps to retain focus and gives ample breathing room even for long reads. This is modern web's take on reading articles. Some applications show a light horizontal bar telling you how much have you finished. Apart from that the text gets the highest precedence and that is much helpful.

**The second example I have is Windows 8.1's news application.**

[image]

This application takes the full screen and presents news article in the multi column layout. The pages scroll horizontally. Even in this approach they have lots of whitespace which is helpful in reading. This application takes cues from the real world and keeps the presentation grounded in how real world newspapers do it. (besides the horizontal scroll). I do use this app to read content, and it does not feel much odd either.

The linked question has an article which requires a vertical scroll in a multi-column layout, that is most definitely wrong. **Your scroll should flow with the direction of the content.**

If you are looking for heuristics, then readability heuristics would apply here too.

- The amount of whitespace.
- Balanced number of paragraphs and text.
- Punctuated by images which are unobtrusive.
- The amount of words on single line. Line width.